# How to make an efficient hashCode?

Tags: java, performance, hashcode

I have three hashCode methods as follows, I prioritised them based on their efficiency. I am wondering if there is any other way to make a more efficient hashCode method.

```
1) public int hashCode() { //terrible
     return 5; 
   }
2) public int hashCode() { //a bit less terrible
     return name.length; 
   }
3) public int hashCode() { //better
     final int prime = 31;
     int result = 1;
     result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
     return result;
   }
```

Comment: the first one just returns...5.. what is that vene good for?

Comment: Side note: `name.length` is not _a bit better_ it's _a bit less terrible_ :P

Comment: why don't autogenerate it?

Comment: Here's a novel idea... how about `return name.hashCode();`. The only thing that seems to affect your hashcode is the value of `name`. If it's a `String` it will already return a good hashcode. Edit: Apparently it's not a `String`, but an array. You can either return its hashcode, or use `Arrays.hashCode()` to generate it.

Comment: For a peaceful life, don't mess with hash-code :D

Comment: @Minzkraut read the comment right in front of the method.

Comment: @BackSlash good idea I reflected that in the question.

Comment: @JordiCastilla give me an example plz

Comment: @Kayaman how about if it was not a String?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31067446/3850595

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ that has a great influence on performance why not?

Comment: @JordiCastilla that is similar to my third solution, whats the difference, I do not get it sorry.

Comment: your solution is autogenerated, same as mine, **this is the correct way to do it** except in counted cases. Have you readed all the answer? you know why `hashCode()` is important? you know what is equals and why override it?

Comment: Efficiency is a subjective measure that will depend a lot on the context. Do you need fast insertions and/or lookups in a hashed data structure? What are the distribution characteristics of your input data? Most of the time, do not try to optimize before you encounter performance issues and have pinpointed the actual bottleneck(s).

Comment: @dotvav I am concerned with lookups.

Comment: Comparing the CPU time taken by different methods that do different things, and saying the fastest method if the most *efficient* is flawed. And what makes you think that the final method is *inefficient*?

Comment: @Raedwald I am not saying that is inefficient, I am just wondering if there is any better way to do that.

Answer (score 6):

There is no surefire way to guarantee that your `hashcode` function is optimal because it is measured by two different metrics.

- **Efficiency** - How quick it is to calculate.
- **Collisions** - What is the chance of collision.

Your:

1. Maximises efficiency at the expense of collisions.
2. Finds a spot somwhere in the middle - but still not good.
3. Least efficient but best for avoiding collisions - still not necessarily best.

You have to find the balance yourself.

Sometimes it is obvious when there is a very efficient method that never collides (e.g. the `ordinal` of an `enum`).

Sometimes memoising the values is a good solution - this way even a very inefficient method can be mitigated because it is only ever calculated once. There is an obvious emeory cost to this which also must be balanced.

Sometimes the overall functionality of your code contributes to your choice. Say you want to put `File` objects in a `HashMap`. A number of options are clear:

1. Use the hashcode of the file name.
2. Use the hashcode of the file path.
3. Use a crc of the contents of the file.
4. Use the hashcode of the SHA1 digest of the contents of the file.

**Why collisions are bad**

One of the main uses of `hashcode` is when inserting objects into a `HashMap`. The algorithm requests a hash code from the object and uses that to decide which bucket to put the object in. If the hash collides with another object there will be another object in that bucket, in which case the bucket will have to grow which costs time. If all hashes are unique then the map will be one item per bucket and thus maximally efficient.

See the excellent WikiPedia article on [Hash Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for a deeper discussion on how `HashMap` works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would you please elaborate on collision? does that mean two different values having the same hash codes? In case that ids are unique or names are unique what is the best approach? from your file example, I reckon you would choose my second solution?

Comment: @Jack - See **Why collisions are bad** addition.

Answer (score 4):

> I prioritised them based on their efficiency

Your list is sorted by *ascending* efficiency—if by "efficiency" you mean the performance of your application as opposed to the latency of the `hashCode` method isolated from everything else. A hashcode with bad dispersion will result in a linear or near-linear search through a linked list inside `HashMap`, completely annulling the advantages of a hashtable.

Especially note that, on today's architectures, computation is much cheaper than pointer dereference, and it comes at a *fixed* low cost. A single cache miss is worth a thousand simple arithmetic operations and each pointer dereference is a potential cache miss.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would you please elaborate on pointer dereference? Also I am a bit confused which one is better then?

Comment: On Java level, pointer dereference happens whenever you access an object (you read the reference to it and then read from the memory location it points to). The best hashcode is 3) because it will cause the best distribution of entries in a hashtable, making them accessible in O(1) time instead of O(n).

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you have a better solution? 4th option? I generated that by eclipse why prime is always 31? and result is 1?

Comment: The boilerplate you have starts making sense only with more than one component contributing to the hashcode. Result is just _initialized_ to 1 which is the neutral element with respect to multiplication. 31 is quoted as optimized for English-alphabet strings because they come from a range of 26 characters. The essential property is that it is a prime.

Comment: Would not it better to have 31 + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode()); rather than what I have? Why should I perform that multiplication then?

Comment: As already suggested, just `return name == null? 0 : name.hashCode();` would be perfectly enough. Which is BTW precisely what [`Objects.hashCode(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object)) does for you. So you could just say `return Objects.hashCode(name);`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the valuable answers so far, I'd like to add some other methods to consider:

---

3a):

```
public int hashCode() {
     return Objects.hashCode(name);
}
```

Not many pros/cons in terms of performance, but a bit more concise.

---

4.) You should either provide more information about the class that you are talking about, or reconsider your design. But using a class as the key of a hash map when the *only* property of this class is a `String`, then you *might* also be able to just use the String directly. So option 4 is:

```
// Changing this...
Map<Key, Value> map;
map.put(key, value);
Value value = map.get(key);

// ... to this:
Map<String, Value> map;
map.put(key.getName(), value);
Value value = map.get(key.getName());
```

(And if this is not possible, because the "name" of a `Key` might change after it has been created, you're in bigger trouble anyhow - see the next point)

---

5.) Maybe you can precompute the hash code. In fact, this is also done in the `java.lang.String` class:

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
    ...

    /** Cache the hash code for the string */
    private int hash; // Default to 0
```

But of course, this **only makes sense for immutable classes**. You should be aware of the fact that using *mutable* classes as keys of a `Map` is "dangerous" and may lead to consistency errors, and should only be done when you're absolutely sure that the instances that are used as keys won't change.

So *if* you want to use your class as the keys, and maybe your class even has more fields than just a single one, then you could store the hash code as a field:

```
class Key 
{
    private final String name;
    ... // Other fields...

    private final int hashCode;

    Key(String name, ...)
    {
        this.name = name;
        ... // Other fields

        // Pre-compute and store the hash code:
        this.hashCode = computeHashCode();
    }


    private int computeHashCode()
    {
        int result = 31;
        result = 31 * result + Objects.hashCode(name);
        result = 31 * result + ... // Other fields
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is going a different path - basically it is not answer, but a question: why do you worry about the performance of `hashCode()`?

Did you exhaustive profiling of your application and found that there is a performance problem originating from that one method on some of your objects?

If the answer to that question is "no" ... then - why do you think you need to worry about this one method? Why do you think that the default, generated by eclipse, probably used billions of times each day ... isn't good enough for you?

See [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) for explanations why it is in general a very bad idea to waste ones time with such questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I know hashcode, is to important in performing sorts or finding items so I think efficiency of hashcode method would have direct impact on performance.

Comment: That is exactly my point: you "think" that is has an impact on performance. I am pretty sure: there are 10, 20, 50 other "things" in your code that have a more severe impact on the overall performance of your application. Don't get me wrong; it is important to understand "what is going on"; but if `hashCode()` turns out to be the most relevant "performance killer" in your application ... then your application is already of extraordinary quality.

Comment: You are right, the reason that I am asking is to have a better idea about hashcode and its effects on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are better alternatives.

[xxHash](https://code.google.com/p/xxhash/) or [MurmurHash3](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3) are general-purpose hashing algorithms that are both faster and better in quality.

Comment: thanks, is there any java builtin solution? just to avoid external libraries.

Comment: @Jack No, but an extra library should not be a problem. Otherwise you can just copy a hashing routine into your project - AFAIU the algorithms are rather small and the permissive license allows you to do so.

Comment: xxHash and MurmurHash are great for hashing binary data, but they are not particularly convenient (or fast) for on-heap data. To xxHash a String you'll have to convert it to bytes first, which will cost way more than calling `String#hashCode()`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Good xxHash implementation is faster even for strings (except very short ones). I've verified this using JMH, though this is obvious from the design of xxHash: it processes input by the blocks of 8 characters while the default hashCode is calculated char-by-char. No conversion is needed: `charAt` is enough. xxHash can be easily adapted for streaming API, i.e. it can be used for arbitrary objects: `new XXHash().append(id).append(name).append(value).hash()`.

Comment: Hm... maybe you and I are talking about different xxHash-java projects? In [this class](https://github.com/jpountz/lz4-java/blob/master/src/java/net/jpountz/xxhash/StreamingXXHash32.java) all I see is `update(byte[] buf, int off, int len)`.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't have any existing implementation in mind, but just the algorithm. In that case the trouble will be how to cheaply move chars into longs, which are the essence of xxHash's speed. Copying and shifting will be unavoidable, removing any advantage.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Right, making a streaming xxhash is not straightforward but doable. Anyway this isn't my point. I wanted to say that 1) you don't need to *convert* or *copy* strings or arrays in order to calculate their xxhash; 2) for large enough strings or arrays xxhash is faster than traditional implementation of polynomial hashCode; 3) the quality of xxhash is a lot better than of polynomial hashCode.

Comment: 3) is uncontestable, but 1) (and consequently 2) is not obviously so. `charAt(i)` gets you two bytes, but to exploit xxhash's efficiency you need to pack four chars into a long. This will involve copying into a `long` variable, along with shifting. The whole code block _may_ be JIT-transformed into something more direct, but even in the optimistic case it's an unsafe bet.

Comment: xxhash fundamentally relies on something inapplicable to Java strings: reinterpreting a 4-word block inside an array of 16-bit words as a single `long` value and loading it into a CPU register with a single instruction. In Java we could use `Unsafe.readLong()` for this kind of stuff, but that won't work for Strings. I would certainly be thrilled to see evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik [Here is the benchmark](https://gist.github.com/apangin/5912c4d90f875c3b1c05)

Comment: Cool. The Unsafe code is indeed fast, but breaks into the String using reflection. It's still slower than regular code for low double-digit string lengths. Altogether these are still mixed results, given the typical distribution of string lengths in an application (I guess lengths above 100 figure with less than 1%). Generalizing this to arbitrary object graphs would be even more challenging, especially performance-wise. I could hardly recommend it as a replacement for the traditional idiom.