# Flipping over the cards in a Matching Pairs Game

Tags: java, android

I am creating a matching pairs game, i have it so when the two cards match they stay up, i do this by creating two integer variables and adding card 1 and card 2 to one variable respectively. They are checked to see if they match and if they do they'll stay up if not they'll flip over.

I have a rough idea how i want to do it but no clue how to write it in code. The steps i am trying to achieve are as follows, flip the cards over where their image id on the card is equal to the pending image, but how will i write that id code?

Any help anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need to create 2 integers, better create a `Card` and `Deck` classes and override equals, something like:

```
class Deck {
    List<Card> cards;  // maybe you need a matrix Card[][] cards?
}

class Card {
    int value;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + value;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Card other = (Card) obj;
        if (value != other.value)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

After you can take the 2 cards and just do:

```
Card card1 = // take the card number 1
Card card2 = // take the card number 2

if (card1.equals(card2)) {
    // are equals, leave up
} else {
    // NOT equals, flip over
}
```

Comment: Just as a sidenote question. Is there a perference in writing the class and null check like this, since `instanceof` would do both and shorten the code aswell.

Comment: @KevinEsche this `hashCode` and `equals` are autogenerated by eclipse, maybe you are rigth, but I don't like to play being god and always leave them as created... xDDDD Please kindly check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31067446/3850595) for longer explanation